# How to stream video files from gridfs with .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, video, streaming

Suppose that I have fairly large videos (200+ MB) stored in MongoDB's GridFS. Given an ID, I could query for a video to play in the client-side.

**Using Asp.Net with C#, I want to know how to stream a video files retrieved from GridFS to client-side's video player.** I saw many examples using byte array to read from the file stream before plugging it into the video player, but I am afraid that would hog server's RAM if there are many requests at the same time. I planned to use HTML5 video player (or any free progressive-download player) for this as well, but I also do not have much knowledge over it just yet.

Below are part of the C# code that I tried to retrieve a file from GridFS but unable to decide what to do next. The .aspx page to this C# code is still left untouched (WebForm .aspx file).

```
String id = Request.QueryString["id"];
var url = new MongoUrl("mongodb://localhost");
var Client = new MongoClient(url);
var db = Client.GetServer().GetDatabase("local");
if (db.GridFS.ExistsById(new ObjectId(id)))
{
    var vid = db.GridFS.FindOneById(new ObjectId(id));
    using(var fs = vid.OpenRead())
    {

    }
}
```